# Error: node_modules directory is missing. Please run `npm install` in your project directory

Tags: react-native, expo

```
expo start  
[21:03:34] Starting project at /home/sadaif/Documents/React-Native-App/my
[21:03:35] Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
[21:03:35] Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
[21:03:41] Error: node_modules directory is missing. Please run `npm install` in your project directory.
[21:03:41] Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project.
[21:03:41] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

I run this command `npm install` but noting happened 
then i run these commands

```
rm -rf node_modules  
rm package-lock.json  
npm cache clear --force  
npm install
```

When I run command `expo start` then this error show in the terminal .I'm Using first time expo cli i m a beginner so that's why have no idea how to fix this issue if anyone know please help me.

Comment: Have you run `npm install` in your project directory? Are you running `expo start` in your project directory?

Comment: i edit my question please check and yes i run npm install and the run expo start but the error remain same and i use npm version 6.6.0

Comment: Which version of expo are you using? After running `npm install` is there a `node_modules` folder in the project directory?

Comment: expo version 2.7.0 no there is no module folder in my project directory

Comment: That is very strange do you get the same issues if you start a new project?

Comment: where have you cloned the project from ?

Comment: yes the issue remain same and when create new project by running expo init the app will generated but with following errors

Comment: Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/sadaif/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/1f/7b'

Unhandled rejection Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/sadaif/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/1f/07'

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://npm.community>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sadaif/.npm/_logs/2019-01-24T16_48_22_224Z-debug.log
[21:48:22] Process exited with non-zero code: 1
[21:48:22]

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi not cloned the project create from scratch

Comment: There looks like there are some permission issues. I think that could be the source of your problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either you are using Mac or Ubuntu the directory you have created the project in needs superuser permissions to modify it.

either run all commands with `sudo` or change the ownership 
`sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config`

or re-install the `node` with

`npm install -g node@latest --unsafe-perm`